# ANDROID not granting permission

Tags: android

im my application, it does not grant the permission for gps location update control. In logcat it shows 
                                                                                         11-09 12:00:45.496: WARN/PackageManager(86): Not granting permission android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES to package com.ars.application (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x7e46)

I have included the permission for this in manifest.xml as

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

What is the mistake in this for not getting the permission??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asifkt,

Please note the CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES permission has:
android:protectionLevel="signature",
which means only applications built into the system image can have this permission.

Comment: @100rabh, Could you please explain this?? i didnt understand this. How can i get this permission??

Comment: You can't use CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES permission for developing apps that are not pre-built into Android.

Comment: @asifkt Are you trying to access cell tower location?

Comment: No. I have to get GPs position in every minutes.. What should i do to get location updates??

Comment: @asifkt Then you just need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION & ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissionscheck this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655

Comment: @100rabh, I used this method to get gps postion. But is not notifying the method OnlocationChanged() of listener class. listener is an extension of LocationListener.                                            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (long)0, (float)0, listener);

Comment: asifkt , better try this http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/ for real time update of location

Comment: For mapping between string permissions and numbers: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html